# How to fix RecyclerView OnClick gap display bug?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm setting up a RecyclerView who contains mulptiple ImageButtons,
Each ImageButton has a OnClick action (launch an Activity)
My problem is, the OnClick action is not working on ImageButtons, but in a little space between each ImageButton (if I want to click on 1st button, I have to click on the space between 1st and 2nd Button)

I've tried changing image size

RecyclerView Adapter:

```
   public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the ImageButton in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int currentCategory = mData.get(position).getImage();
        holder.categoriesButton.setImageResource(currentCategory);
    }

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageButton categoriesButton;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            categoriesButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_Button_Category_id);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    public int getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id).getImage();
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
```

RecyclerLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_Button_Category_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And this is in my MainActivity:

```
  private void setRecyclerViewOn(ArrayList<Category> list) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_id);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, list);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivity(createIntent(position));
}
```

Expected results: Click listener have to be on each ImageButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding on click listener on onBindView() instead

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int currentCategory = mData.get(position).getImage();
        holder.categoriesButton.setImageResource(currentCategory);
        holder.vategoriesButton.setOnClickListener(...)
    }
```